# Mule - Mapping data from JSON

Tags: json, mapping, mule

I get a `JSON` message in `Mule` like this:

```
{
"Id":1,
"Description":"Test",
"IssueId":16
}
```

I want to map the `IssueId` with other values, for example:

```
16 = 1000
17 = 1010
18 = 1020
```

What is the best way to do that? Is it advisable to do it with a properties file to modify it in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookup() feature of DataWeave, see: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-language-introduction#calling-external-flows

Answer (score 0):

You can use property file to do this to keep them configurable.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put your Initial value and Increment value in properties file and calculate for other value in Java component.
This will help you to configure them accordingly in future.